# C++ Stringstream initializations

Tags: c++, initialization, stringstream, copy-initialization, direct-initialization

I have two code snippets:

This does not compile:

```
std::string reverseSentence(std::string sentence) {
    std::stringstream stream = sentence;
}
```

This does:

```
std::stringstream stream (sentence);
```

It's my understanding that `T foo = expr` is `T foo(expr)`. Thus, aren't the two stringstream initializations equivalent? Why is one compiling and the other not?

Comment: Nit, may also consider passing `sentence` as a reference rather than a copy -- unless that was the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [constructor of `std::basic_stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) taking `std::string` is marked as `explicit`, it's not considered in [copy initalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) like `std::stringstream stream = sentence;`.

`std::stringstream stream (sentence);` is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), which considers `explicit` constructors too.

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization: copy-initialization only considers non-[explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) constructors and non-explicit user-defined [conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), while direct-initialization considers all constructors and all user-defined conversion functions.